# JSON API style sideloading in Rails ActiveModel::Serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, serialization

I'm trying to build a [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/format/) style API using AM::Serializer. I'm running into an issue with sideloading.

I want to be able to build JSON that looks like:

```
{
    "primaries": [{
        "id": 123,
        "data": "Hello world.",
        "links": {
            "secondaries": [ 1, 2, 3 ]
        }
    }],
    "linked" : {
        "secondaries": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "data": "test1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "data": "test2"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "data": "test3"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The code I've been able to come up with looks like:

```
class PrimarySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :data

  has_many :secondaries, key: :secondaries, root: :secondaries
  embed :ids, include: true
end
```

Which generates JSON that looks like:

```
{
    "primaries": [{
        "id": 123,
        "data": "Hello world.",
        "secondaries": [ 1, 2, 3 ]
    }],
    "secondaries": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "data": "test1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "data": "test2"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "data": "test3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to override the location of the in-element `secondaries` and sideloaded `secondaries` such that they live in child nodes `link` and `linked`?

The above code is an abstraction of the actual code and may not work. Hopefully it illustrates the point sufficiently.

Thanks!

Comment: any success with this?

Comment: No. I gave up and used jbuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveModel Serializers can do this. The problem is that the built-in association methods are to restrictive. Instead you must build up the `links` & `linked` parts manually.

(This answer refers to the [stable 0.8.1 version of ActiveModel Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-8-stable))

Here's a Gist with a complete JSON-API solution https://gist.github.com/mars/97a637560109b8ddfb27

Example:

```
class ExampleSerializer < JsonApiSerializer # see Gist for superclass
  attributes :id, :name, :links

  def links
    {
      things: object.things.map(&:id),
      whatzits: object.whatzits.map(&:id)
    }
  end

  def as_json(*args)
    hash = super(*args)

    hash[:linked] = {
      things: ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(
          object.things,
          each_serializer: ThingsSerializer
        ).as_json,
      whatzits: ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(
          object.whatzits,
          each_serializer: WhatzitsSerializer
        ).as_json
    }

    hash
  end

end
```